# sqlldr issue with ORA-00054

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

let me explain this....

I had running 1 session of sqlldr while I run indexes into table for 6 fields... now the indexes are completed but the sqlldr running very slow it load one file after each 30 minute...

now when I do any alter to set the indexes off it won't let me do it and though an error of ( ORA-000054 and ORA-000604) even if I run another sqlldr....

any suggestion will be highly appreciate.... bellow is sample of my control files header...

```
OPTIONS(DIRECT=TRUE,ROWS=10000,BINDSIZE=209700000,readsize=209700000)
load data 
append
into table name
FIELDS TERMINATED by '!'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED by '"'
trailing nullcols
```

When I run following query

```
select * from dba_dml_locks

session_id,owner,name,mode_held,mode_requested,last_convert,blocking_others
123,username,tablename,exclusive,none,1228,not blocking
```

ps: I update the question as I mixed up two question sorry guys

Comment: Can you check and see if you have a full tablespace?

Comment: Does your table B have any foreign key constraints or triggers that reference A, perhaps? It isn't quite clear to me what you are doing where, and when; you said "this indexes are in table B" but then "but table B which have no index". Which table is `idx_test` on, and what state is that index in - completely built and valid? (And are you testing the performance impact of indexes on your production system!?)

Comment: Hi thanks for replay... my table spaces have space there is no issue with that... idx_test is running on table A... and all indexes analysed and working...all indexes are in tableA ... there is no index in table B...

Comment: sorry guys... I had mixed up the question with another one... I updated the question please check maybe now it make sense..